# How to enable runc logs when running with containerd or docker

Tags: docker, containerd, runc

Looking at the `runc` code, it looks it uses logrus to write its logs when `--debug` flag is enabled. I am using `runc` through `docker` and `containerd`. I was wondering how I can enable/view these runc logs in such a scenario or if I can set this `--debug` flag inside containerd?